# Elisp: Old variable values seem to stick

Tags: emacs, elisp

Beginner question for emacs lisp.

In my .emacs I have written the following:

```
(defun line-text-up-with-parentheses-above()
  (interactive)
  (line-text-up-with-char-above "("))

(defun line-text-up-with-char-above(charval)
  (interactive)
  (setq now-point   (point))
  (previous-line)
  (setq above-point (point))
  (forward-char)
  (search-forward charval (line-end-position) nil)
  (setq above-paren (point))
  (goto-char now-point)
  (insert (make-string (- above-paren above-point) ? )))

(global-set-key (kbd "\<C-S-iso-lefttab>") 'line-text-up-with-parentheses-above)
```

The function intends to line the text at the point up with the character after the "(" on the line above it.

Everything seem to work fine, unless the function is called twice in a row. In this case, the text before the point advances exactly the same amount as last time.

Seems like the variables aren't being set the second time around.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Many thanks!

Comment: It looks like the title to the question has been truncated, please update it.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem - it works fine for me on Emacs 24.0.91.1

Answer (score 4):

You calculate the intended indentation. However, you always insert it regardless of how many spaces the current line contains.

You could either simply delete the spaces on the current line before inserting the new spaces, or you could try to calculate the number of spaces needed and insert or delete, as needed.

Some hints:

- By using `setq` you are using global variables, try to bind them using `let`.
- Instead of recording where the point is before you move it around and restore it afterwards, you could use the special construct `save-excursion`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. +1 for save-excursion. I thought that 'let' would work, but it seems to be giving the same results.

Comment: The problem is not that the variables get the wrong value. The problem is that you always insert spaces corresponding to the indentation, regardless of how many spaces the line originally contained. In effect, your code ADDS X spaces rather than indenting to column X.

Comment: @Lindydancer: the function adds X - (original column) spaces, which is correct, *if* point was at the first non-whitespace character when the function was called.

Answer (score 1):

I think the variables are being set correctly (although Lindydancer is correct to suggest `let` instead of `setq`). And your function works fine for me if I call it with point at the first non-whitespace character on the line you want to 'line up'. The only problem I see is that the function lines up with wherever point is when you call it, which is not correct if point is not at the first non-whitespace character.

You can fix this be adding `(back-to-indentation)` immediately after `(interactive)` in `line-text-up-with-char-above`. Actually, once you wrap everything in `save-excursion` you'll want to add `back-to-indentation` as the first function within the `save-excursion` form.

Answer (score 1):

Protip: [align](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AlignCommands) and specifically align-regexp.